# Change a textbutton's text within a listview

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I have a listview in which i have a textbutton I'm trying to change the text, but I haven't been able to achieve it.

Here are some of the things i've tried so far:

```
listview1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.TextButton.Text:= 'Hi';
listview1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemEditObjects.TextButton.Text := 'Hi';

i := listview1.Selected.Index;
ListView1.Items[i].Text:= 'Hi';
```

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TListViewItem.TListViewItemObjects.TextButton

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I already tested it and it does not work... I don't know how to solve this

Comment: The link that @Sami provided says you have to change the properties of `TListviewItem` you are changing the properties of `TListView` itself.

Comment: can you give me an example, please?